# Linear transformation function handle

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, cell-array, function-handle

Assume I have the legendre polynomials in cell Array P as function handles. Now I use the linear transformation x = 2/3*t-1. Now I want to get a cell array Q which has the transformation function handle. 
So P = [1, @(x) x, 1/2*(3*x^2-1),...] to Q = [1,@(t) 2/3*t-1,...]

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this site might be better suited to your question?: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kmeixner I think this is more a programming question than a math question

Comment: @user307380 You'd be better off using symbolic functions for that task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the Symbolic Toolbox, you can do it this way:

1. Convert your cell array of anonymous functions to a cell array of strings
2. Do the change of variable using [`subs`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html). This produces [symbolic objects](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) as output.
3. Convert from symbolic objects to anonymous functions using [`matlabFunction`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html):

Code:

```
P = {@(x) 1, @(x) x, @(x) 1/2*(3*x^2-1)};        %// data 
f = cellfun(@func2str, P, 'uniformoutput', 0);   %// step 1
Q = arrayfun(@(k) matlabFunction(subs(f{k}(5:end), 'x', '2/3*t-1')), 1:numel(P),...
    'uniformoutput', 0);                         %// steps 2 and 3.
    %// Note that the "(5:end)" part is used for removing the initial "@(x)"
    %// from the string obtained from the function
```

Result in this example:

```
Q{1} =
    @()1.0
Q{2} =
    @(t)t.*(2.0./3.0)-1.0
Q{3} =
    @(t)(t.*(2.0./3.0)-1.0).^2.*(3.0./2.0)-1.0./2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in basic MATLAB also: you just need to compose the anonymous functions of the polynomials with the transformation function. Before writing the solution, I want to point out that your posting is inconsistent: you talk about cell arrays of function handles, but you use matrix notation for your definitions.

The code:

```
%// The original polynomials
P = {@(x) 1,  @(x) x,  @(x) 1/2*(3*x^2-1)};

%// The transformation function
x = @(t)2/3*t-1;

%// The composition
Q = cellfun(@(f) @(t)f(x(t)), P, 'UniformOutput', false );
```

The result is going to be a cell array of functions that will do the stuff:

```
x == 1  --> t == 3
P{2}(1) --> 1
Q{2}(3) --> 1
```